# Windows 7 batch file to delete specified files in a path with spaces

Tags: windows-7, batch

I'm trying to get a batch to work but it seems it can't find the specified file. I'd like the batch to do the following:

1. Kill my IP camera software
2. Wait a few seconds to ensure the software has shutdown
3. Delete the archive (video) files, except for one file (`Sources.SRCS.lxa`)
4. Again, wait to ensure the files have all been deleted
5. Restart the IP camera software
6. Close the batch window

I think I'm close but I would really appreciate a set of "pro eyes" on this to get it working correctly. This is where I am so far (which I "patched" together after a little light reading but at this point I'm quite stuck):

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im DVRClient.exe
timeout 10
for %%i in (N:\TRENDnet\"TRENDnetVIEW Pro"\"Archive Files"\*) do if not %%~nxi == Sources.SRCS.lxa del %%i
timeout 20
C:\Program Files (x86)\TRENDnet\TRENDnetVIEW Pro\DVRClient.exe
exit
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: If there is no other files (except for that sources.srcs.xla file) you need to protect, you may move the file to somewhere else, remove the "archive files" folder itself by rd /s /q command, recreate it and get it back to the place again. Or, if all the files you need to remove have the same extension, you can just rename the extension on the file to protect first and commit "del *.ext" and re-rename it. Using attrib +R can do similar tricks. What I'm saying is that, at least, you don't have to use FOR command for this case.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I think I thought I was better at batch writing than I actually am.. ;) I decided that the FOR cmd wasn't worth the headache and simply used the rename command as you suggested since the files are all of the same type. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Principle with quotes is that the entire path (not partial directories) must be quoted.
Therefore convert

```
N:\TRENDnet\"TRENDnetVIEW Pro"\"Archive Files"\*
```

into

```
"N:\TRENDnet\TRENDnetVIEW Pro\Archive Files\*"
```

And also convert

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\TRENDnet\TRENDnetVIEW Pro\DVRClient.exe
```

into

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TRENDnet\TRENDnetVIEW Pro\DVRClient.exe"
```

Finally, you might consider surrounding all occurrences of variable `%%i` by quotes: `"%%i"` so if there was filename with space in `%%i`, your processing will not fail.

Comment: Thanks for the tip miroxlav, it's been a very long time since I've had to use these commmands, and sadly (due to time) it'll be a very long time before I use them again... cheers.